# Insert a non-character if a criteria is TRUE

Tags: r, street-address

Is it possible to insert a non-character, in this case -, if a particular criteria is met?

For example:
If there are five numeric characters (12345), then insert a - after the 2nd numeric character (12-345).

I am trying to fix street addresses.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "abc 12345 def"
sub("([0-9]{2})([0-9]{3})", "\\1-\\2", s)
# "abc 12-345 def"
```

This will find first instance of 5 numbers in a row and add a "-" after the second number. See http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html for R regex syntax.

Comment: It's not really clear to me how much of the above to explain, but I'd be happy to answer any specific questions about the expression. For R regex syntax, see http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html

Comment: Neatly it works for numeric values and for vectors too. It also inserts a "-" if there are more than five numeric characters

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies. The solution works great!